# how to stream a json using flink?

Tags: json, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-sql

i 'm actually working on a stream, receiving a bunch of strings and need to make a count of all the strings. the sums is aggragated, that mean for the second record the sum was added to the day before
the output must be some json file looking like

```
{
"aggregationType" : "day",
"days before" : 2,
"aggregates" : [
    {"date" : "2018-03-03",
    "sum" : 120},
  {"date" :"2018-03-04",
  "sum" : 203}
  ]
}
```

i created a stream looking like :

```
val eventStream : DataStream [String] = 
eventStream
    .addSource(source)
    .keyBy("")
    .TimeWindow(Time.days(1), Time.days(1))
    .trigger(new MyTriggerFunc)
    .aggregation(new MyAggregationFunc)
    .addSink(sink)
```

thank you in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note on working with JSON in Flink:

Use `JSONDeserializationSchema` to deserialize the events, which will produce `ObjectNode`s. You can map the `ObjectNode` to `YourObject` for convenience or continue working with the `ObjectNode`.

Tutorial on working with `ObjectNode`: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model

Back to your case, you can do it like the following:

```
val eventStream : DataStream [ObjectNode] = 
oneMinuteAgg
    .addSource(source)
    .windowAll()
    .TimeWindow(Time.minutes(1))
    .trigger(new MyTriggerFunc)
    .aggregation(new MyAggregationFunc)
```

will output a stream of 1min aggregates

```
[     
      {
      "date" :2018-03-03
      "sum" : 120
      }, 
      {
      "date" :2018-03-03
      "sum" : 120
      }
]
```

then chain another operator to the "oneMinuteAgg" that will add the 1min aggregates into 1day aggregates:

```
[...]
oneMinuteAgg
        .windowAll()
        .TimeWindow(Time.days(1))
        .trigger(new Whatever)
        .aggregation(new YourDayAggF)
```

that will output what you need

```
{
    "aggregationType" : "day"
    "days before" : 4
    "aggregates : [{
      "date" :2018-03-03
      "sum" : 120
      }, 
      {
      "date" :2018-03-03
      "sum" : 120
      }]
}
```

I used `windowAll()` assuming you don't need to key the stream.

Comment: thank u for the help ,  had some few things to edit on the post, its not that simple :)

Comment: the mean problem actually is how to make that json look like that 
i dont know to to format it like that. never worked with it :(

Comment: @TheEliteOne check the updated answer. You need to either work with `ObjectNode` to build your JSON or map the `ObjectNode` to `YourObject` then create the JSON from `YourObject`. Check the tutorial I linked.

Comment: the mean problem is that i need to key the stream
i tried using the windowAll() but its showing some error